# Symfony2 Nested forms and ManyToMany relations

Tags: symfony, many-to-many, nested-forms

I'm trying to handle a form which is quite complex for me...

We have Collections, which contain books (OneToMany), with articles(OneToMany) and their authors (ManyToMany).

The user can edit a book: he can add or remove an article, and add or remove some authors for each article. There are nested forms : book>article>author.
If the author is new in the Collection, it is created for that Collection.

Entities descriptions look fine, database is generated by the console and seems consistent.

This is working fine if I don't have to deal with authors using the book edition form. If the author exists, I have a duplicate entry bug. If the author is new, I have a "Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship" bug.

Here is the code:

```
public function onSuccess(Book $book)
{   
    $this->em->persist($book);

    foreach($book->getArticles() as $article)  
    {
        $article->setUrlname($this->mu->generateUrlname($article->getName()));
        $article->setBook($book);

        // Saving (and creating) the authors of the book
        foreach ($this->collectionWithAuthors->getAuthors() as $existAuthor){      
            foreach($article->getAuthors() as $author) {                        
                $authorUrlname=$this->mu->generateUrlname($author->getFirstname().' '.$author->getLastname());
                if ( $existAuthor->getUrlname() ==  $authorUrlname) { // The author is existing
                    $article->addAuthor($existAuthor);
                    $this->em->persist($existAuthor);
                }else{                                                // New Author
                    $newAuthor = new Author();                                
                    $newAuthor->setCollection($this->collectionWithBaseArticles);
                    $newAuthor->setLastname($author->getLastname());
                    $newAuthor->setFirstname($author->getFirstname());
                    $newAuthor->setUrlname($authorUrlname);
                    $this->em->persist($newAuthor);
                    $article->addAuthor($newAuthor);                          
                }
            }
        }
        $this->em->persist($article);

    }
    $this->em->flush();

}
```

I don't know how to use cascades. But the $article->addAuthor() is supposed to call $authors->addArticle():

Article Entity extract

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="bnd\myBundle\Entity\Author", mappedBy="articles")
*/
private $authors;

/**
 * Add authors
 *
 * @param bnd\myBundle\Entity\Author $authors
 * @return Article
 */

public function addAuthor(\bnd\myBundle\Entity\Author $authors)
{
    $this->authors[] = $authors;
    $authors->addArticle($this);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in foreach statement is wrong. Suppose we have next authors:

1. Persisted authors (collectionWithAuthors):

   - John
   - Eric
2. Submitted authors

   - Ada
   - Eric

So for every existing author (John and Eric) the script loop thru new authors:

```
foreach ([John, Eric] as $author) {
    foreach([Ada, Eric] as $newAuthor) {
        // John author: the script persist Ada(right) and Eric(wrong) as new authors
        // Eric author: the script persist Ada(wrong), but not Eric(right)
    }
}
```

The solution is to replace article authors with existing authors (if there is similar)

```
foreach ($article->getAuthors() as $key => $articleAuthor) {
    $authorUrlname=$this->mu->generateUrlname($articleAuthor->getFirstname().' '.$articleAuthor->getLastname());
    $foundAuthor = false;
    // Compare article author with each existing author
    foreach ($this->collectionWithAuthors->getAuthors() as $existAuthor) { 
        if ($existAuthor->getUrlname() ==  $authorUrlname) {
            $foundAuthor = true;
            break; // It has found similar author no need to look further
        }
    }

    // Use $existAuthor as found one, otherwise use $articleAuthor
    if ($foundAuthor) {
        $article->removeAuthor($articleAuthor); // Remove submitted author, so he wont be persisted to database
        $article->addAuthor($existAuthor);
    } else {
        // Here you dont need to create new author                          
        $articleAuthor->setCollection($this->collectionWithBaseArticles);
        $articleAuthor->setUrlname($authorUrlname);
    }

    ...
}

$this->_em->persist($article);
```

You have noticed i removed any author persistent from the loop, to persist these authors its better to set cascade={'persist'} in $authors annotation of Article Entity Class

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Author", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(...)
 */
protected $authors;
```

**UPD:**

I forgot to mention one thing about cascade persistent. To persist relation betweed article and author you also have to add relation to author entity. Edit the `addAuthor()` method in the `Article` entity as below:

```
public function addAuthor(Author $author)
{
    // Only add author relation if the article does not have it already
    if (!$this->authors->contains($author)) {
        $this->authors[] = $author;
        $author->addArticle($this);
    }
}
```

Also, it's a good practice to define default values for a collection of entities in the constructor:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

// ...

public function __construct()
{
    $this->authors = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your option was the first I tried. But your code is nicer. This solves the duplicate entry bug, but I still have an exception with new authors :A new entity was found through the relationship 'bnd\myBundle\Entity\Article#authors' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: bnd\myBundle\Entity\Author@000000000234544f00000000501971d4. Explicitly persist the new entity or configure cascading persist operations on the relationship. If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'bnd\myBundle\Entity\Author#__toString()' to get a clue.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understand well, with the persist annotation, the author is automatically persisted when the article is persisted. I removed $authors->addArticle($this) from the method addAuthor($authors). This seems to be working fine:  new authors are added. However, the link between the article and the author is not persisted: the table author_article is not updated...

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, you did not have to remove the link between these entities. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm starting to get it... I still had a duplicate entry. I think this was due to the $article->removeAuthor($articleAuthor); which was not working on both sides. I fixed this by adding $authors->removeArticle($this) to the removeAuthor method.

Comment: There's still a little issue when inserting new authors. If the author is not in the database, then it is created, but not linked to the article.

Comment: Check whether you have setAuthors($authors) method in the Article entity and remove it. When the data is submitted by user and is valid the form maps it to the entity by calling corresponding "set" or "add" methods, not sure about the order though

Comment: I only have the addAuthor() method, and no setAuthor(). In your code, $article->addAuthor($existAuthor); is only written in case of existing author (and it works). Why don't we use the same logic in case of new author ? : $article->addAuthor($articleAuthor). I tried that, but it does not work either. Does the new author have to be persisted or flushed before being linked to the article ? I tried different options, but none work...

Comment: Ok, I got it by persisting the new Author, before explicitly adding it to the article.